# Docker Compose file to Create a container with multiple Images

Tags: docker-compose

Docker Compose file to Create a container with multiple Images
I need to build a container using the following images.

Python
DotNetCore 2.0

have created a docker-compose.yml file as below. Am trying to create one container for each image and do linking between the containers. But its failing can you please correct me the compose file.

Also after the container is created how can i check what are the images inside the container.

…
version: “1.0”

services:
phython:
image: python

dotnetcore:
image: microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
links:

```
phython:hub
```

Please suggest how to go ahead .

Comment: Please use Code Sample {} button to format your sample code so it is readable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able I would recommend using docker-compose 3.0 instead of 1.0. The 'links' attribute is deprecated in 3.0 which now favors just setting up a simple user-defined bridge network. Your docker-compose would be as follows:

```
version: 3.0
  services:
    phython:
      image: python:latest
      networks:
        - my-net
    dotnetcore:
      image: microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
      networks:
        - my-net
  networks:
    my-net:
      driver: bridge
```